# PostgreSQL: How do I search for records against a datetime field while ignoring the year?

Tags: postgresql

I want to retrieve all the records that match a date excluding year and seconds.
For example, I'm searching against these records:

```
2023-10-15 12:00:00
2023-10-17 12:00:00
2023-10-23 13:23:00 <--- want to return this
2024-10-23 13:23:10 <--- want to return this
```

I currently have this code but is there a cleaner shorter way to write the query?

```
whereRaw('
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM event.start_at) = ? AND 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM event.start_at) = ? AND
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM event.start_at) = ? AND
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM event.start_at) = ?',
        [10, 23, 13, 23]
)
```

Comment: Do you want this in PostgreSQL or PHP Laravel?

Comment: Something like?: `select row(extract(month from date_trunc('seconds', now())), extract(day from date_trunc('seconds', now()))) = row(10, 16); t`.

Comment: @Schwern Both. I'll be writing the query for PHP.

Comment: Since performance is going to be terrible anyway, I would use `to_char(event.start_at, 'MMDDHH24MI') = '10231323'`

Comment: @MikeOrganek It's ugly, but performance can be great: Just create an index using the same expression: `CREATE INDEX idx_ugly_one ON event(to_char(start_at, 'MMDDHH24MI'));`